# Deriving the ghost Lagrangian in Peskin and Schroeder

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, yang-mills, quantization

On page 514 of Peskin and Schroeder, the book derives

$$\tag{16.31} \det\bigg(\frac{1}{g}\partial^\mu D_\mu\bigg)=\int\mathcal{D}c\mathcal{D}\overline{c}\exp\bigg[i\int d^4x\overline{c}(-\partial^\mu D_\mu)c\bigg]$$

From which we get the ghost Lagrangian $$\tag{16.32}\mathcal{L}_{\text{ghost}}=\overline{c}^a(-\partial^2\delta^{ac}-g\partial^\mu f^{abc}A_\mu ^b)c^c$$

But how? My understanding is that $c$ is a vector of $\dim G$ number of componenets, with each component a Grassmann number, and $D_\mu=\partial_\mu-ig A_\mu ^a t^a$ on page 490. What is $c^a$?

Comment: $c^a$s the "$a$"-th Grassmann-valued component of the vector $c$. I do not know what you mean by "each component a spinor."

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, not spinor but a Grassmann valued component. But how do we go from $t^a$ to $f^{abc}$?

Comment: The gauge fields $A_\mu$ live in the [adjoint representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation), for which the generators $t^a$ have the matrix elements $(t^a)^{bc}=f^{abc}$, where $f^{abc}$ are the structure constants.

Comment: @Andrew Does that mean $c$ is a vector with number of components equal to the dimension of the adjoint transformation?

Comment: $c^a$ are $d_A$ Grassman fields that transform in the adjoint representation of the gauge group, where $d_A$ is the dimension of the adjoint rep.